# Can't join 2 descendants under the same collection of their parents

Tags: c#, inheritance, collections

This is my class structure :

```
public class MainWindow
{
    public List<FirstBar> FirstBars { get; set; }
    public List<Foo> SelectedFoos { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        FirstBars = new List<FirstBar>();
        SelectedFoos = new List<Foo>();
    }
}

public abstract class Foo { public bool IsSelected { get; set; } }
public class FirstBar : Foo { public List<SecondBar> SecondBar { get; set; } }
public class SecondBar : Foo { }
```

...and then I wanna fill in the `SelectedFoos` with / under this condition(s) :

> I want to find all `FirstBar`s which `IsSelected==true`. And if I
>   found a `FirstBar` which `IsSelected==false`, I then look for each
>   `SecondBar` under `FirstBar` which `IsSelected==true`.

So, based on that condition, I wrote this down somewhere after the collection initialization in the `MainWindow`'s constructor :

```
/*assume below collections are already filled with some items.*/
SelectedFoos = FirstBars.Where(x => x.IsSelected).ToList(); //this is the error, below code is kinda irrelevant.
SelectedFoos.AddRange(FirstBars.Where(x => !x.IsSelected).SelectMany(x => x.SecondBars).Where(x => x.IsSelected).ToList();
```

But, editor says it's wrong / error :

> Cannot **implicitly convert** type `'...FirstBar>'` to `'...Foo>'`

Then, I tried :

```
/*assume below collections are already filled with some items.*/
SelectedFoos = (List<Foo>)FirstBars.Where(x => x.IsSelected).ToList(); //this is the error, below code is kinda irrelevant.
SelectedFoos.AddRange((List<Foo>)FirstBars.Where(x => !x.IsSelected).SelectMany(x => x.SecondBars).Where(x => x.IsSelected).ToList();
```

After that the error changed to :

> Cannot **convert** type `'...FirstBar>'` to `'...Foo>'`

**My reasoning is** (which apparently wrong somehow), since they (`FirstBar` and `SecondBar`) both have a same parent (`Foo`), then they can be combined in a list of their parent (`List<Foo>`).

Btw, I know it can be solved if I split them into different collections, but it's better to have 1 list (since in my real project code, there's also `ThirdBar` (the collection of this is inside the `SecondBar`) and `FourthBar` (the collection of this is inside the `ThirdBar`).

Can anyone explains what caused this? I feel that I am kinda lost on some fundamental of inheritance with this problem.

Thank you

Comment: It's really important to take note of where the errors are occurring - your `AddRange` call is irrelevant, as the compile-time error is on the previous line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with the parents here (and you're not doing a join anyway) - and it's not even *in* your second line. The problem is just that a `List<FirstBar>` isn't a `List<Foo>`, even though every `FirstBar` is a `Foo`. As of .NET 4, this is easy to fix using generic covariance:

```
SelectedFoos = FirstBars.Where(x => x.IsSelected).ToList<Foo>();
```

The explicit type argument on `ToList` means this is basically equivalent to:

```
IEnumerable<FirstBar> tmp = Enumerable.Where<FirstBar>(FirstBars, x => x.IsSelected);
SelectedFoos = Enumerable.ToList<Foo>(tmp);
```

That's using the fact that an `IEnumerable<FirstBar>` expression can be converted to `IEnumerable<Foo>` with covariance.

Comment: cr*p, I knew it. I also tried `.ToList(List<Foo>)` (silly i know) actually before. And yes, it's not literally "SQL's join". Kinda ambigue apparently. Thanks